# Coffeescript - Improve algorithm for increasing grouping

Tags: coffeescript

The code below works but I am wondering if there is a better way that maybe uses some of the features of coffeescript that I am unfamiliar with.

The problem is this, I need to page items but the paging increases each time.

If I take the number 20 for example, it would create the following pages:

1 - 3
4 - 7
8 - 15
16 - 20

I have the following test and code which does pass:

```
module 'Remainder',
  setup: ->
    @remainder = 20

test 'splits remainder incrementally', ->
  parts = @remainder.increasingSplit()
  equal parts[0], '1 - 3', ''
  equal parts[1], '4 - 7', ''
  equal parts[2], '8 - 15', ''
  equal parts[3], '16 - 20', ''

Number.prototype.increasingSplit = ->
  start = 1
  nextSplit = 3
  parts = []
  finished = false
  while !finished
    if nextSplit > @
      parts.push "#{start} - #{@}"
      break

    parts.push "#{start} - #{nextSplit}"
    start = nextSplit + 1
    nextSplit = nextSplit * 2 + 1

  parts
```

Comment: You can replace `finished = false; while !finished` by `loop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing the algorithm too much, you can try this:

```
Number::increasingSplit = ->
  start = 1
  nextSplit = 3
  parts = []
  while start <= @
    parts.push "#{start} - #{Math.min nextSplit, @}"
    start = nextSplit + 1
    nextSplit = nextSplit * 2 + 1
  parts
```

The changes were:

- replacing `.prototype` with `::`,
- removing of the `finished` variable (which was not being used effectively because the `break` anyway) and the `break` altogether and changing the condition to `start <= @`,
- using only one `parts.push <part>`, with the minimum between `nextSplit` and `@` as the top.

---

Also, i'd advice against extending the Number prototype in this case. Extending the prototype of primitive types can sometimes cause weird problems, like:

```
Number::isFour = -> @ is 4
console.log 4.isFour() # -> false
```

That happens because inside that function `@` will be a Number *object* instead of a primitive number, thus making the `=== 4` comparison always fail. That would not happen if you define `isFour` as a standalone function:

```
isFour = (n) -> n is 4
console.log isFour 4 # -> true
```

So, i'd prefer this version of `incrasingSplit`:

```
increasingSplit = (n) ->
  start = 1
  nextSplit = 3
  parts = []
  while start <= n
    parts.push "#{start} - #{Math.min nextSplit, n}"
    start = nextSplit + 1
    nextSplit = nextSplit * 2 + 1
  parts
```

---

Finally, if you don't mind recursion, you can go with a more FP-style algorithm :)

```
increasingSplit = (n, start = 1, nextSplit = 3) ->
  if start > n
    []
  else
    part = "#{start} - #{Math.min nextSplit, n}"
    rest = increasingSplit n, nextSplit + 1, nextSplit * 2 + 1
    [part, rest...]
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.

I am unfamiliar with:

 [part, rest...]

What does the ... mean in the second element?

Comment: @dagda1 the `...` (aka "splats") there make the `rest` array expand into the resulting array; the whole expression is equivalent to `[part].concat(rest)`.